# Problems with Django Templatetag `regroup`

Tags: django, django-templates

When using the `regroup` templatetag I encountered a problem where a Queryset would produce an empty list (`[]`) as a result.

A similar Queryset (e.g. a Set with the same columns and filters however one filtervalue differed) worked perfectly fine.

My Query looks like this:

```
GraZeichen.objects.filter(gtid__id=gtid).values("id", "findno").exclude(findno=None, formid=0).annotate(values_id=GroupConcat(
        "formid", separator=',')).annotate(values_en=GroupConcat("fombez_en", separator=','))
```

and my Template looks like this:

```
{% regroup zeichen|dictsort:'values_de' by values_en as zeichen_by_val %} 
 
{% for valgroup in zeichen_by_val %}
{{ valgroup.grouper }} ({{ valgroup.list|length }})
<div>
  {% for zeichen in valgroup.list %}
  <div>
    <a href="alink">
      <img ...>
    </a>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As I said it works perfectly fine for some `gtid`s, but if I compare the printed Queryset of `gtid`s where it worked with the ones where it did not I can see no difference.

What are the cases, where regroup would return an empty list?

Comment: I looked into the [Git-Code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/64e5ef1f17cd18cb8ca24f4e7107dfd28c18b378/django/template/defaulttags.py) (line 259f) for the Django templates and it seems, that the referenced column was not found am I right? However this would still not explain why it sometimes works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution. However I did not fully understand why it now works. Sorting by the ids does the trick for me:

```
{% regroup zeichen|dictsort:'values_id' by values_de as zeichen_by_val %}
```